# ng2-modal-module : passing data on success events

Tags: angular

This is where I have gotten to. Cant figure out how to send my form with the success event. Is that even possible? because I want to save the details of the user in MongoDB, how do I fetch them in this case. Have been stuck at it for the past ~10 hrs

app.component.html

```
    <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="displayModal()">Add</button>
    <ng2-modal-window id="addUserModal"></ng2-modal-window>
```

app.component.ts

```
    displayModal(){

    let successEventName = 'successEvent'; 
    let cancelEventName = 'cancelEvent';

    this.modal.resetEventsSubscribers([successEventName, cancelEventName]);

    this.modal.showModal("addUserModal",{
        title: 'Add User',
        htmlContent: `
            <form [formGroup]="myForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="firstname" class="form-control" formControlName="firstname" #fname>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="lastname" class="form-control" formControlName="lastname">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="firstName">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email">
                </div>
            </form>
        `,
        buttons: {
            success: { event: successEventName },
            cancel: { event: cancelEventName }    
        }
    });

    this.pubsub.subscribe(successEventName, (data) => {
        console.log('Success triggered!', data); 
    });

    this.pubsub.subscribe(cancelEventName, (data) => {  
        console.log('cancelEventName triggered!', data);  
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the ng2-modal-module, but assuming that you know how to receive a success event, the rest should be straightforward. Since you use reactive forms API, you should create the instance of myForm somewhere (not shown in your code sample).

The variable myForm holds the data entered in the form, and you can access the entire object using `this.myForm.value`. If you wanted to access a value of a particular form control, you could do it like this:

```
this.myForm.value.firstName
```

Then use this value with your Http or HttpClient object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but there lies my exact problem. The success event / cancel event are not under my control. The buttons / events are provided by ng2-modal-module and I have absolutely zero control over them. So I cant find a way to pass myForm. Is there a better way to create modals in angular 2/4 that you know of would be a great help. (I know a few ways but always stuck at passing data and handling multiple modals).

Comment: Sure thing. I'll try this Yakov. Thanks for your help. We need more people like you :)

Comment: Thanks! If you want to clone me using JavaScript (ES6), read about the spread operator here: https://yakovfain.com/2017/08/10/javascript-rest-and-spread-operators :)

Comment: I tried using Angular Material. I get the following error. "Unexpected value 'MdDialog' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation." Do you have an idea about it ? I am also searching for this issue on google. So far no luck. (Using angular 4 btw)

Comment: Have you installed angular material and cdk?

Comment: Yes, I did..Followed their steps and installed material, cdk,animations etc.